# FLUTTER, Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, sdk, androidx

- When I compile it gives me this error,* Help me.

  ''' D8: Program type already present: io.flutter.BuildConfig
  com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  Program type already present: io.flutter.BuildConfig
      at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:131)
      at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:118)
      at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
      at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:444)
      at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:335)
      at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:39)
      at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
      at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
      at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
      at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
      at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:55)
      at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$1.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:105)
      at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$1.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:99)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
      at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
      at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
  Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
      at com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:55)
      at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(:11)
      at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:116)
      ... 30 more
  Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: io.flutter.BuildConfig
      at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:21)
      at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:7)
      at com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:36)
      ... 32 more

  Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 '''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure, there was not instant run for this application. And/or try to uninstall application, if it was before.
- Try to rename/reduce package name. Just fo testing purpose, I remember it happens because of some issues with naming.

Comment: @Matt99 no problem.